# Reading text file line by line in C using fscanf

Tags: c, file-io

I am trying to get this program to read from a text file and write to another text file line by line. I have it reading the file and writing the file, but it only does the last line. I have been googling for days and tried several different methods suggested, but this is the closest I have gotten. I feel like I am very close. I also have it printing to screen just to help with debugging.

This is my code so far:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define MAX 20

int main()
{
    char fileInName[MAX];
    char fileOutName[MAX];
    int empNum = 0;
    char givenName[MAX];
    char surname[MAX];
    char dept[MAX];
    float ytd;
    float payRate;
    float hours;

    printf("Enter the name of the input file (Maximum of 15 characters): ");
    scanf("%s", fileInName);
    FILE *inFile = fopen(fileInName, "r");

    if(access(fileInName, F_OK) == -1)
    {
        printf("Input file does not exist! Program terminating.");

        exit(0);
    }

    printf("Enter the name of the file to hold the results (Maximum of 20 characters): ");
    scanf("%s", fileOutName);
    FILE *outFile = fopen(fileOutName, "w");

    while(fscanf(inFile, "%d\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%f\t%f\t%f\n", &empNum, givenName,
                    surname, dept, &ytd, &payRate, &hours) != EOF);
    {
            printf("%d\t%s %s\t%s\t$%.2f\t$%.2f\t%.2f\n",
                    empNum, givenName, surname, dept, ytd, payRate, hours);

            fprintf(outFile, "%d\t", empNum);
            fprintf(outFile, "%s\t", givenName);
            fprintf(outFile, "%s\t", surname);
            fprintf(outFile, "%s\t", dept);
            fprintf(outFile, "$%.2f\t", ytd);
            fprintf(outFile, "$%.2f\t", payRate);
            fprintf(outFile, "%.2f\n", hours);

    }

    fclose(inFile);
    fclose(outFile);

    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
6  Ab-Karim   Khasby      Acct   110100.00  13.24   40.0    
10 Castillo   Jorge       Acct    66600.00  17.87   64.5    
22 Cofer      Matthew     Acct    36600.00  10.00   10.0
24 Davidson   Jacory      Acct   110090.00  41.3    36.7    
13 Foley      Zachery     Acct     1358.34  16.22   53.51
5  Gonzalez   Eduardo     DP     110090.00  10.00    1.0    
3  Gutierrez  Thomas      Mgt    673478.34     187.56   40.0    
1  Holder     David       Mgt    134234.34      67.42   56.25   
4  Johnsen    Samuel      Sales  11345.22   23.77   67.3    
12 Koirala    Akriti      Sales    234.56      17.56    38.9    
17 Lasater    William     Sales   2342.34      27.86    45.6    
7  Martin     Colton      Sales  67000.00   34.23   40.0    
86 Perkins    Felix       Inven  12345.78   13.24   40.0    
66 Reasons    Joshua      Inven 109998.75   57.87   64.5    
51 Schultz    Jesse       Inven 206600.00   10.00   10.0    
38 Stevens    Marissa     Inven  78342.00   51.3    36.75
```

Expected Output is for it to look pretty much the same in the new text file.

Current output:

```
38  Stevens Marissa Inven   $78342.00   $51.30  36.75
```

Comment: The culprit is a `;` typo at the start of the `while` loop as in `while(...);`. So that loop reads all the file, and afterwards you output once: the last data read.

Comment: Oh my god. Haha. Thank you. I was trying a do while loop at one time and I guess I forgot to remove that when I went back to while loop. I have been pulling my hair out over this and it was something so dumb. Thank you very much

Comment: As a point of style when you need an empty loop: use empty braces to indicate it's not a mistake.

Comment: If `access` fails, it certainly does not imply that the file does not exist.  Writing `"Input file does not exist! Program terminating."` to stdout (error messages belong on stderr) is confusing if access is denied due to a permissions error.  `perror` is your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
while(fscanf(inFile, "%d\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%f\t%f\t%f\n", &empNum, givenName,
                surname, dept, &ytd, &payRate, &hours) != EOF);
```

creates an empty loop because of the `;` at the end. That loop reads all the data, and then outputs the last set read.

You should use

```
while(fscanf(inFile, "%d\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%f\t%f\t%f\n", &empNum, givenName,
                surname, dept, &ytd, &payRate, &hours) != EOF)
```